# C++ Inserting into a linked list

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that modifies a linked list. The problem I am having is when inserting nodes into the linked list. The first few nodes are inserted and moved properly, but when reaching the end of the linked list some nodes are either removed or not displayed.

Function for inserting

```
void LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos)
{
    Node *temp1 = new Node;
    temp1->data = num;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

    Node *temp2 = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
}
```

Node structure

```
        struct Node
        {
            int data;
            Node *next;
        };

        int size;
        Node *head, *tail;
```

Driver code

```
    nums.insert(1, 0); // 1 in location 0
    nums.insert(5, 4); // 5 in location 4
    nums.insert(3, 7); // 3 in location 7
```

List before insert

```
8  6  7  8  0  9
```

List after insert

```
1  8  6  7  5  8
```

Expected after insert

```
1  8  6  7  5  8  0  9  3
```

Would the values excluded from being display needed to be stored and inserted afterwards? Or is the inserting itself not being coded properly/missing elements?

Thanks for your help.

Full code

```
#include "linkedlist.h"



LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *temp;

        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            temp = head->next;

            // deletes head
            delete head;

            // goes to next element
            head = temp;
        }
    }
}

void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node *temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << temp->data << "\t";

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::append(int num)
{
    // list is empty
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node;

        head->data = num;
        head->next = nullptr;

        // sets tail to head
        tail = head;
    }

    else
    {
        // creates new node
        Node *temp = new Node;

        // sets new node data
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = nullptr;

        // sets previous tail link to new node
        tail->next = temp;

        // sets this node to new tail
        tail = temp;
    }

    // increments size
    size++;
}

void LinkedList::pop()
{
    if(size > 1)
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        // loops to node before tail
        while(temp->next->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // deletes tail
        delete tail;

        // sets new tail
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }

    // if there's only one item
    else if(size == 1)
    {
        Node *temp = tail;

        // head and tail are now null
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;

        // deletes node
        delete temp;
    }

    size--;
}


int LinkedList::min()
{

    int min = head->data;

    struct Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        if(min > temp->data)
        {
            min = temp->data;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return min;
}

int LinkedList::max()
{
    int max = head->data;

    struct Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        if(max < temp->data)
        {
            max = temp->data;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return max;
}

int LinkedList::mean()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;

    struct Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        sum += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    average = sum / size;

    return average;
}


void LinkedList::sort()
{
    Node *current1 = head;
    Node *current2 = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if(current1->data < current2->data)
            {
                int temp = current1->data;

                current1->data = current2->data;

                current2->data = temp;
            }

            current2 = current2->next;
        }

        current2 = head;
        current1 = head->next;

        for(int p = 0; p < i; p++)
        {
            current1 = current1->next;
        }
    }
}

void LinkedList::reverse()
{
    Node *current1 = head;
    Node *current2 = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if(current1->data > current2->data)
            {
                int temp = current1->data;

                current1->data = current2->data;

                current2->data = temp;
            }

            current2 = current2->next;
        }

        current2 = head;
        current1 = head->next;

        for(int p = 0; p < i; p++)
        {
            current1 = current1->next;
        }
    }
}

int LinkedList::linearSearch(int key)
{
    Node *search = nullptr;
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while(current != NULL && current->data != key)
    {
        count++;
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if(current != NULL)
    {
        search = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    key = count;
    return key;
}

void LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos)
{
    Node *temp1 = new Node;
    temp1->data = num;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

    Node *temp2 = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
}
```

Comment: does every node contain head and tail

Comment: @asmmo yes, they do

Comment: Not according to this code. `Node` contains `data` and `next` ; that's *all*. Your `LinkedList` is what contains `head` and `tail`.

Comment: the correct implementation shouldn't be like that. And plz, provide minimal producible program https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @WhozCraig My mistake, those are variables under the protected part of the class header. Would inserting 0, 9, and 3 at the tail of the function remedy this?

Comment: @jaytmitch You are linking your new node and existing nodes wrong. Draw it out if you have to.

Comment: I don't really understand that question. Insertion in a specific position in a linked list requires a counter and some pointer walking; that's pretty much it. And fyi, that `for` loop is a recipe for disaster if you're given a pos that exceeds the length of your list, which is unchecked in your positional insertion member. (or for that matter, even updated there).

Comment: you did not update the size in your code

Comment: ` for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)` will also need a test to ensure that the program doesn't march off the end of the list before reaching the `pos`th `node`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `size` member that your `display` function uses, but you never increment it in `insert`.  So while the element gets added, you don't increase the size of the list.

Answer (score -2):

Reading your whole code and getting to the solution may consume lot of time but if you want i have a code ready which is properly working. If you wanted to use this. Please go for it and also, please feel free to ask my anything though this [link](https://maskottchen.tech/)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
int data;
node *next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
node *head,*tail;
public:
linked_list()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void add_node(int n)
{
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = n;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}

node* gethead()
{
    return head;
}

static void display(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << head->data << endl;
        display(head->next);
    }
}

static void concatenate(node *a,node *b)
{
    if( a != NULL && b!= NULL )
    {
        if (a->next == NULL)
            a->next = b;
        else
            concatenate(a->next,b);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Either a or b is NULL\n";
    }
}
};

 int main()
{
 linked_list a;
 a.add_node(1);
 a.add_node(2);
 linked_list b;
 b.add_node(3);
 b.add_node(4);
 linked_list::concatenate(a.gethead(),b.gethead());
 linked_list::display(a.gethead());
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer, and code-only answers teach [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Linking offsite to further help isn't useful in the long run because the link will rot, depriving future askers of important information. You may be able to salvage this answer by explaining what you did and why in the body of the answer.